# Redactor Editor automatically strips classes from div

Tags: javascript, html, redactor

I am using Impervi Redactor  as a editor on my website where i set some html generated using xml and xslt. It is driving me round the bend though as it seems to want to change the code to how it sees fit whenever I press the source button. For example if I hit source and create a ...

```
    <div class="myclass">some content</div>
```

It then for no apparent reason strips the class from the , so when I hit source again it has been changed to...

```
     <div>some content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [allowedAttr](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-allowedAttr) like:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
allowedAttr:  [
    ['div', 'class'],
]});
```

even you can allow several attributes like:

```
['img', ['src', 'alt']]
```

You can also find [list of all available settings](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/) for Impervi Redactor